# Canon SDK backward compatibility

Tags: c#, canon-sdk

I've developed some photo application for internal use, working with Canon 5D Mark II through Canon EOS SDK 2.13.
As for now, I've tried to upgrade SDK to 3.5.
The application was totally ruined (e.g., when I try to open liveview, the camera flatters its shutter on-off and doesn't send liveview stream).
So, I've got some questions.
1. Is Canon EOS SDK 3.5 backward compatible with Canon 5D Mark II?
2. Can I still use 32-bit SDK with .NET Framework based 32-bit application under 64-bit Windows?
3. Are there some changes with C# code using the 3.5 SDK in comparence with 2.13?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any experience with this SDK. But using a quick fix to make your old project compile again with a Win32 assembly is to build on a target platform (32-bit).

Build -> Configuration Manager -> Project
choose on column Platform 
New -> Then set new platform to x86.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a breaking change in version 3.4 where the file and IO related functions switched from uint to ulong.
Also the PictureStyleDesc struct has changed in 3.2 and the DirectoryItemInfo struct in 3.4

[My project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp) is compatible with all versions and if you are only interested in the changes, have a look at the SDKMethods.cs and SDKStructs.cs files in the SDK folder. Those files include both versions and a way to find out which Canon SDK version is used.